# How exactly setQueryMode of VO works?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am new to Oracle ADF and i am stuck in understanding concept of how queryMode works.
can some one please explain me following
--> what data will be in VO cache,EO cache when i do just vo.executeQuery()
--> what happens when i use setQueryMode() and does vo.executeQuery() with different modes like QUERY_MODE_SCAN_VIEW_ROWS,QUERY_MODE_SCAN_ENTITY_ROWS,QUERY_MODE_SCAN_DATABASE_TABLES|QUERY_MODE_SCAN_ENTITY_ROWS on the below table.
--> When we apply ViewCriteria with the above modes how it behaves.

lets take following table called InfoTable

Id|StartDate|EndDate|Country|Status
56|01-APR-16|31-DEC-16|US|A
57|01-APR-16|31-DEC-16|IND|A
58|14-APR-16|31-DEC-16|UK|N

Note:Here PrimarKey(id,StartDate,EndDate)

Can we visualize what data in EO,VO cache like data base tables?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

QueryMode determines how VOs works with data:

1. **QUERY_MODE_SCAN_DATABASE_TABLES**: always gets data from database (default mode);
2. **QUERY_MODE_SCAN_VIEW_ROWS**: takes data from existing rows without requerying them from database(in memory);
3. **QUERY_MODE_SCAN_ENTITY_ROWS**: uses entity cache (only for entity-based VOs)

**Sorting**:

When you invoking sorting method for QUERY_MODE_SCAN_DATABASE_TABLES, then your original sql-query changing by AdfBc engine to:

```
select * 
from ([original select defined in your ViewObject])  
order by field1;
```

In case of QUERY_MODE_SCAN_VIEW_ROWS sorting uses Comparable interface in memory;

**Filtering**:

Filtering process uses ViewCriteria, which also has queryMode:

**CRITERIA_MODE_QUERY**: uses Database to retrieve filter data. As in example of sorting AdfBc also dynamically surrounds your original query with external select with where clause and predicates adjusted by ViewCriteria:

```
 select * 
   from ([original select defined in your ViewObject]) 
    where field1=:field1 and field2 between :field2_start and :field2_end;
```

**CRITERIA_MODE_CACHE**: all data restrictions appears in memory.